# Copy arrays as individual elements into another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

EDIT:

```
var G = require('generatorics');
var newArray = [];
   for (var data of G.permutation(['a', 'b'])) {
      console.log(data);

      //this returns an array in every iteration as below
      //data = ['a', 'b'] //iteration 1
      //data = ['b', 'a'] //iteration 2
      //data = ['b', 'b'] //iteration 3 
      //data = ['a', 'a'] //iteration 4
```

I want to add these 'data' arrays as individual arrays into the newArray declared at the top every iteration. The spread notation I have below, adds all the elements but it all goes in as individual elements.

```
newArray.push(...data);
    }
```

I am looking for something like this as final output.

```
newArray = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']];
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `something`? Maybe `newArray = [...something]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want *copies* of the arrays not references to the same array. You can mix `map` and `[...]` or `slice()` to add a copy rather than just a reference to the item to a new array:

```js
let something = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]

let newArray = something.map(item => [...item]) // copy of each array

console.log(newArray)

// not the same references
console.log(newArray[0] === something[0])
```

EDIT:

If `something` is an iterator rather than an array, you can still to almost the same thing, just using a for loop instead:

```js
// Some iterator from a library //
let arr = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
function* gen() {
    yield*  arr
}
let something = gen()
/////////////////////////////

// Array.from can iterate the iteraor
let newArray = Array.from(something, (data) => [...data])

console.log(newArray)
console.log(newArray[0] === arr[0])
```

Edit II:

This works fine for me (it's basically the same as above):

```js
// var G = require('generatorics'); // loading with script
var newArray = Array.from(G.permutation(['a', 'b']), (data) => [...data]);
console.log(newArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/generatorics@1.1.0/generatorics.js"></script>
```

Comment: UV - It seems that you were right about the OPs intention.

Comment: Edited my question. I wouldn't know the data array values beforehand. This doesn't work for me :(

Comment: @SamT see the edit. It's the same idea, you just can't directly use `map` with an iterator.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work too. The goal really is I want to keep pushing the data array to the newArray inside every iteration. And I don't know the value of data array before the iteration.

Comment: @SamT You need to update the question with enough detail that we have some idea that `something` is. You're making us guess. If it's not an iterator and it's not an array, what is it?

Comment: @SamT The above edit works for me with that NPM package.

Comment: It worked. When I use Array.from within the for loop it doesn't But when I use your one liner, it works as expected. Thank you for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the spread (`...`), so you're pushing the array `data` each time:

```
newArray.push(data);
```

Demonstration:

```js
var newArray = [];

var something = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']];

for (var data of something ){
  newArray.push(data);
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Or, if you want to make it even more compact, remove the `for...of` loop entirely and just use `map`:

```js
var newArray = [];

var something = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']];

newArray = something.map(data => data);

console.log(newArray);
```

Or, since you're making one array the same as another, just assign them that way:

```js
var something = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']];

var newArray = something;

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy with map...

```
let newArray = something.map(data => data);
```

Or with slice...

```
let newArray = something.slice();
```

Or [a bunch more ways](https://www.briangonzalez.org/post/copying-array-javascript).

Comment: Both map and slice keeps only the last array value which ['e', 'f'] in the newArray. I want to keep adding all the 'data' values one after the other and get a complete list in newArray.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you want to copy the arrays into the `newArray`? If you want to copy the arrays, and not just push a reference to them into `newArray`, you'll want to use `.slice`.

So: `newArray.push(data.slice());`

Keep in mind that `.slice` produces a shallow copy not a deep copy, so any nested objects will still be references but primitives (like integers and strings) will be copied.